# Javascript form submit doesn't submit properly

Tags: javascript, php, forms, sweetalert

I have this very simple form using [Sweet Alert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) and for some reason can't get it to work. When I click on the link it triggers the alert and when the alert is confirmed it reloads the page because it submits the form.

But for some reason when `$_POST['delete_alert']` is undefined.

My code to trigger the alert:

```
<a id="sa-warning">Delete</a>
```

My form:

```
<form id="form" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="delete_alert" value="delete">Delete</button>
</form>
```

And my Javascript:

```
$('#sa-warning').click(function() {
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this alert.",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
  }, function() {
    document.forms["form"].submit();
  });
});
```

I'm testing wheter the form has been submitted properly using this PHP code which is located on index.php:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['delete_alert'])) { 
    echo "form is submitted correctly"; 
} else { 
    echo "something is wrong"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I cant see any input other than submit that can store information, so that can be the explanation why is `$_POST['delete_alert']` undefined

Comment: @JTC the button itself should submit a name=value pair, if given in the HTML.

Comment: Should `document.forms["form"].submit();` be `$('#form').submit()`? I think that document.forms expects an index not an ID or name.

Comment: @Nijn does the `<a id="sa-warning">` indeed have no `href` attribute at all?

Comment: It has no href attribute, but even if I add an href = "#", it still doesn't work.

Comment: _If_ it does have an `href` attribute, you trigger a `GET` request, because it's not the form that's submitted, but the `<a id="sa-warning">`. Add a `return false;` (quick 'n dirty) to the `click` handler.

Comment: Adding the href and changing POST into GET doesn't work out either.

Comment: The submit button is only included in `POST` data when you submit the form by clicking on that button, not when you submit with Javascript (how is it supposed to know which submit buttons it should send?).

Comment: Pff I thought I checked this already.. Removing the submit button and adding a simple input. This works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in `document.forms["form"].submit();`

HTML forms send the submit `name=value` only if button is clicked. 
In this case it is not.

So i think you should use `click` instead of `submit`, but in your case it wont work, because the click will be catched by your javascript function.

So this is why the best solution si to use `input`

Answer (score 0):

maybe is work : http://rachmanzz.github.io/AlertlightJS

```
$('#sa-warning').click(function(){
    alertlightJS.$swalPost({     // $swalGet for GET Method
        title : "Are you sure?",
        text  : "You will not be able to recover this alert.",
        type  : "warning",
        confirmText:"Yes, delete it!",
        cancelText:"No!"
    },{
        url : "index.php",
        input   : {
            delete_alert:'delete'
        }
    },function(isConfirm,data,swal){
        if(isConfirm){
                swal(['receive',data['data']]);
        }else{
            swal(['cancel','thanks']);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight change in my form was needed. The submit button is not clicked when the form is submitted via Javascript. Thus the value of 'delete_alert' is never set.

Removing the submit button and adding an input field resolved the problem.

The correct form:

```
<form id="form" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete_alert' value="delete" />
</form>
```

Thanks to [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) for pointing this out.